# How to build RegEx which skip any braces '[' characters inside a word or just hit last character?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Regex I try
([)(\w)*(])

Text I need for example

```
Hello[world], where the [world]] gone?
```

Second [world]] -> the the braces ] before last brace ']' should ignored.

So match must skip any ] inside word. I want make whole [world]] is match.

See Demo [regexr.com/5u6d2](http://regexr.com/5u6d2)

**Here's what I need exactly in picture:**

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `(\[)+(\w)*(\])+?`

Comment: because `\w` does not match `]`.  how about `\[.*\]`?

Comment: You need a lookahead, `(\[)(\w)*(\])(?!])`